# Do different zones have a resting temperature?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

In Oxygen not Included different areas have different temperatures, and you can create and move heat around.

What I have not been able to figure out is whether this is a closed system or not.

Does heat leak in or out from the third dimension? If I stop adding heat to a cold biome, will it eventually re-freeze? If all my duplicants died and the game ran on for ten hours with nothing running, would the starting zone return to 23C?

Answer (score 1):

There are no special properties of biomes other than what starts in them.  There's no hidden propery of the cold biome that magically removes heat.

Your starting area might eventually get back (down, I assume) to 23C if the average temperature of the asteroid is cool enough, but it won't do it via any implied 3rd dimension heat transfer.

https://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Biome

Comment: Thank you. But that doesn't explain why the 45c area surrounding the starting area does not encroach and spread into the starting zone.

Comment: Abyssalite. It has (almost?) no thermal conductivity, so it is used to isolate the different temp starting biomes. Once you start digging holes through it,  though,  you break the isolation.

Comment: I would say for warmer areas that are not separated by abyssalite, it _will_ eventually encroach and warm up the starting area.  But thermal conduction in this game is fairly slow and it's just a long process.  Maybe there's a mod that would let you run a world for a long time with no Dupes to test this out?

Comment: Worth noting that different materials in the game heat up, cool down and radiate heat and cold at different rates.